# Apply Jquery method to dynamic content in real time

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, dynamic-content

I have a jquery method which highlights all the hashtags in the content which is within containers with .main class:

```
$(".main").markRegExp(/([@]|[#])([a-z])\w+/gmi);
```

And it works fine with initial content. But the content of the containers is dynamic (there is content added with AJAX based on user interactions), so posterior added content is not highlighted. Is there a way to do it?

**Note:** in other similar answers regarding dynamic content I have seen the use of Jquery's on() method, but I do not know if in this case that would be the solution, since the method is not applying an event to the content.

Comment: You would want to re-run this logic any time an ajax request changes the content.  The easiest way to do this is to add this logic to, or call it from, the logic that does the change(s).

Comment: You might want to take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver but I strongly advise Taplar's suggestion.